# Get an image from a UID using typoscriptObjectPath in a Fluid template?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

In my Fluid template I have a uid of a category.
How can I get an image from a field on that category?

I've tried `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.catImage" data="{myuid}" />`

Then something like:

```
lib.catImage = CONTENT
lib.catImage {
    table = sys_category
    current = 1
    select {
        fieldName = cat_image
    }
    renderObj {
        ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did the UID come from? Or: why is there only the UID instead of a Category-object? IMO it would be a cleaner solution to assign the category to the view and not only its UID.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to get [`CONTENT`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) but [`FILES`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html):

```
lib.catImage = FILES
lib.catImage {
  maxItems = 1
  references {
    table = sys_category
    uid.data = field:uid
    fieldName = images
  }

  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    stdWrap.data = file:current:uid
  }
}
```

And call it via `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.catImage" data="{uid: {myuid}}" />`

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, but your comment lead me to realise I have the parent category as an object. So I looped over the subcategories of it to find the one that matches the uid I have. Thank you.